# Gradient of cosine

Tags: vector-analysis

I am quite new to vector calculus and I am not sure how to calculate the following.

Suppose we have three position vectors $\vec{r}_i$,$\vec{r}_j$, and $\vec{r}_k$ in $R^3$.

The angle $\theta_{ijk}$ is the angle between the vector $\vec{r}_{ij}=\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j$ and the vector $\vec{r}_{ik}=\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_k$.

I am interested in calculating the following gradient of the cosine angle:
$\nabla_{\vec{r}_j} \cos(\theta_{ijk})$.

Edit 1 : As pointed out by Travis, the notation above may not make sense. What about the following notation? $\partial\cos(\theta_{ijk})/\partial \vec{r}_j$. I apologize for any nonsense.

How would I compute this? Coud you also tell me a good introductory book?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense: $\theta_{ijk}$ is a function on $R^3 \times R^3 \times R^3 \cong R^9$, but in the expression $\nabla_{\vec{r}_i} \cos \theta_{ijk}$ it is differentiated in the direction $\vec{r}_i$, which is a direction in $R^3$.

Comment: Also, usually one reserves the term *gradient* of a function $f$ for the vector field $\nabla f$, and uses the term *directional derivative* for derivatives $\nabla_{\bf x} f$.

Comment: (Finally, I recommend Rogawski's *Calculus* for this topic.)

Comment: Thanks Travis. I am so sorry about the notation, which I am still trying to get more familiar.